# Python Text Widget appending tab characters ( "\t")

Tags: python

I have this function in my code that just opens a Dialog and open a  text file, so in this file it will extract some specific information, that its just basic numbers. Im extracting them by column, since they displays like this:

1[tab]2.942 2,885   3,013   2170    745 2,91    0,00000             0,000
2[tab]3,065 3,013   3,129   2500    834 3,00    0,00000  V          0,042
3[tab]3,188 3,129   3,261   9813    2449    4,01    0,00000  V          0,084
4[tab]3,307 3,261   3,409   4990    891 5,60    0,00000  V          0,124 [...]

[...]

10[tab]4,731    4,661   4,793   6855    2037    3,37    0,00000 T           0,608
11[tab]4,842    4,793   4,941   2834    829 3,42    0,00000 TV          0,646

I just need the first  numbers, the enumerator, to print it in the Text Widget. The problem is that I`m extracting by column [0:2],and the first 9 numbers are single digit only, so the widget is append the tab character after the 
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9.. and printing like:

1

whitespace

2

whitespace

3

whitespace

10

11

12

I want to remove this spaces.
 Here`s the code:

```
def grab_file(self):   
    self.f = tkFileDialog.askopenfile(mode="r",filetypes=(("Description file","*.desc"),("All files","*.*")))
    self.data_list = self.f.readlines()

    self.f.close()

    del self.data_list[141:]
    del self.data_list[0:62]
    for self.line in self.data_list:
        self.lines = self.line.strip().split("\t")
        self.grab_file_irk.append((self.lines[1]))

    self.grab_file_irk = [w.replace(',', '.')for w in self.grab_file_irk]
    self.grab_file_irk.reverse()

    for i in self.grab_file_irk:
        self.grab_file_floated.append(float(i))

    for self.column in self.data_list:
        self.entry0.insert("end",self.column[0:2] + "\n")
```

Thanks for your time.

Comment: If the lines are all formatted the way you say, how about `self.column[:self.column.find('\t')]`?

Answer (score 0):

You could either find the index of the first tab character directly:

```
self.column[:self.column.find('\t')]
```

or use regex:

```
import re
m = re.match('(\d+)', self.column)
s_num = m.group(0)
```

Comment: Thanks for answering... I was looking for doing some with regex actually, but I didn't understand the answer, I mean... I know where the characters are, is the tab char that separate the columns, if I throw a print, it will be like: 1\t,2\t....9\t,10,11,12,13...the 9th first numbers are single digits, so the first 9th char of the  2 column are tabs...After I match them with the regex, how I prevent them to be inserted?

Comment: I'm not really sure how you're using what you currently have as `column[0:2]`, but can you not just replace this with `m.group(0)` after matching each line as above?

Comment: the group was inserting just the last enumerator on the list...but I could do it with a list comprehension..thanks anyway